# Solution verification on Folland Real analysis, Question 1.26

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

**Problem** Prove that if $E \in \mathscr{M}_\mu$ and $\mu(E) < \infty$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a set $A$ that is a finite union of open intervals such that $\mu(E \Delta A) < \epsilon$, given the fact that if $E \in \mathscr{M}_\mu$, then $$\begin{align} \mu(E) &= \inf \: \{\mu(U): U  \supset E \text{ and $U$ is open} \} \\ &= \sup \: \{ \mu(K): K \subset E \text{ and $K$ is compact}\}. \end{align}$$

**Solution** Let $K$ be a compact set, and $U$ be an open set, both with measure such that $\mu(K) + {\epsilon}/{2} > \mu(E)$ and $\mu(E) + {\epsilon}/{2} > \mu(U)$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collection of every open intervals inside $U$. then there exists a finite $\mathscr{B}' \subset \mathscr{B}$ which covers $K$. Then $F = \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}} B$ is the desired set, because $\mu(E - F) < \mu(E - K) < \epsilon/2$ and $\mu(F - E) < \mu(U - E) < \epsilon/2$.

---

How does it look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $\mathscr{M}_\mu$?

Comment: Some advice: I suggest you briefly explain why the open set $U$ and the compact set $K$ even exist in the first place. I also suggest you write $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{I}_n$ where $\mathcal{I}_n$ is an open interval for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  You should also directly show that $\mu\left(A \triangle E \right)<\epsilon$ after you define $A$ via the finite subcover of $K$.

Comment: @Masacroso It is the notation from Folland real analysis, which I am currently using. It denotes the domain of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure created by the right-continuous increasing function.

Comment: @MatthewH. Thanks! Since I am studying mathematics on my own, such advice helps me a lot!